# Reading From a File Within Same Directory

Tags: java, file-io, groovy, spock, bazel

I am writing a test using the Groovy Spock framework, IntelliJ and Bazel build system. The goal is to read test data from `LamborghiniAventador.obj` located in the same directory as the test file, `Model3dImporterSpec.groovy`.

I am getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

```
def "reading from test file in same directory"() {
  given: "some stuff"
     //do some stuff here

  when: "reading from test file"
    def file = Paths.get("LamborghiniAventador.obj").normalize().toFile()   
    def byteArray = getFileAsByteStream(file.getAbsolutePath())

  then: "file should be read and byte array should not be null"
    byteArray != null;        
}

private static byte[] getFileAsByteStream(String pathToFile) {
  return new File(pathToFile).text.getBytes()
}
```

The path to my file when I search on command line is: `~/Dev/Master/src/test/java/com/censored/api/editor/model3dparsers/LamborghiniAventador.obj`

I can successfully read from a file sitting on my desktop but as soon as I relocate that file within the project space things stop working.

[image: Directory Tree]

How do I read test data from a test file, where the test data file and the test file live in the same directory. This is an easy task in Java (Eclipse). I have looked at a ton of other Stackoverflow questions to no avail so I think I have a serious lack of understanding here. I would love explanation in addition to an answer.

**Edited for Clarification**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my own question with help from @Opal.

1) When you want to access a resource in bazel you need to update the build file by adding in a resources array:

```
resources = ["LamborghiniAventador.obj"],
```

2) `def foo = getClass().getResourceAsStream('LamborghiniAventador.obj')` as suggested by @Opal worked for me once I made change 1). So the code above is now:

```
 def "reading a file in goovy."() {
   when: "reading file from same directory"
     System.out.println("Going to read from a file in same directory")
     def foo = getClass().getResourceAsStream('LamborghiniAventador.obj')
     def byteArray = foo.getBytes()
   then: "file should be read and byte array should not be null"
     byteArray != null; 
 }
```

Comment: not for two days after the post. Will do tomorrow  :)

Comment: Ah, sure. Always forgetting about it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the specification `Model3dImporterSpec.groovy` is located under:

```
src/test/groovy/org/whatever
```

`LamborghiniAventador.obj` file should be located under:

```
src/test/resources/org/whatever
```

Why? Resources files should be kept under the same directory as source files.

Then to load the file use:

```
getClass().classLoader.getResourceAsStream('LamborghiniAventador.obj')
```

Comment: Should this still work if the spec file and the test data file are in the exact same directory?

Comment: my test file is at test/java/com/censor/api/editor/model3dparsers/Model3dImporterSpec.groovy and the data file is now at test/resources/com/censor/api/editor/model3dparsers/LamborghiniAventador.obj and still no luck.  When I convert the resulting InputStream that is returned from your line of code into a byte[] it is null and I get a null pointer exception. Code here: def is = getClass().classLoader.getResourceAsStream('LamborghiniAventador.obj')
    def byteArray = is.getBytes()

Comment: `Model3dImporterSpec.groovy` should be under `test/groovy` - not `test/java`. Do you have this project online? May I have a look?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot put it online due to some client restrictions. I have always kept all of my spec files in test/java/some/path and have never had an issue. Is this just convention or will it prevent certain aspects from working? I appreciate your help. I'm pretty green.

Comment: What build system are you using? How do you run tests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96737/discussion-between-miss-serena-and-opal).

Comment: Opal is right, groovy test code should go under `src/test/groovy` unless you've hacked your gradle build to go off-piste?

Comment: Actually it was partially a bazel issue. I am going to update the question now since I didn't even mention that in the post. I am very new to bazel.